# More than one ManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, managedobjectcontext

In **my managedObjectModel** I have several Entities. I think that it's possible to create **ManagedObjectContext** for each one... If it's true I would like to know:

1. Do I need method **- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel** for each ManagedObjectContext?
2. Do I need method **- (void)saveContext** for each ManagedObjectContext?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that's what you want to do? Can you edit your question with some more detail of why you think you need to do this?

Comment: @jrturton
Sorry for my english... in general, I want to use managedObjectContexts for each Entity. If I have 5 entities I will create 5 managedObjectContexts
Or may be one managedObjectContexts is enough?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your English, I want to know _why_ you want to do this?

Comment: I think that there will some problems if I will work with several Entities (which use 1 managedObjectContexts) at the same time... may be I'm wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do this. A single managed object context is designed to deal with multiple entities, and if there are relationships between your entities, they have to be in the same context.

Separate contexts are useful for background threading and temporary workspaces, as explained rather well [here](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/). Until and unless you need that, stick with a single context.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Core Data Basics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001650-TP1) again and take a look at some [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html) that uses Core Data.

Usually,

- You have one NSManagedObjectModel that is like a schema which provides the descriptions of your entities.
- You have one NSPersistentStoreCoordinator which uses your NSManagedObjectModel to create the DB
- And you have one or more NSManagedObjectContext which are 'scratch pads' which talk to your NSPersistentStoreCoordinator and manage a context of objects. Think of it like a way to have a transaction.

And when you make a project, be sure to check 'Use Core Data' so the project comes with most of it set up for you.